# Update Sitecore from 8.2 to 9.1 - analytics

Tags: xdb, xconnect, contact-facets

I am entering the update solution Sitecore from version 8.2 to version 9.1. I started by upgrading the .NET version and Sitecore libraries to the latest version.

Is there any instruction what should be replaced when it comes to libraries that do not have a new version?

Mainly I mean `Contacts`, `Facets` and related items with:

- Sitecore.Analytics.Outcome
- Sitecore.Analytics.MongoDB
- Sitecore.ContentSearch.Analytics

Comment: If a library doesn't have a new version it must be removed and cannot be kept with the old version. If some classes are missing, use a tool like dotPeek to find where the class is in the new Sitecore version